# How to remove space in inner table when writing an equation?

Tags: tables, spacing, equations

I am using nested tables for an equation as follows:

```
\begin{table}[H]

    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c}

        % Text left of opening bracket.
        \emph{w}\textsubscript{\emph{x},\emph{y}} = \emph{tf}\textsubscript{\emph{x},\emph{y}} * $log\textsubscript{10}$

        % Text in brackets.
        $\left(
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \multirow{2}{*} & 
                \emph{N}\\\cline{2-2} &
                \emph{df}\textsubscript{\emph{x}} \\
            \end{tabular}
        \right)$ \\

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This produces the following:

[image]

But I want to remove the left space in the brackets but so far I have not been able to.

Can anyone advise where I am wrong or suggest an alternative?

Comment: Why are you using nested `tabular` environments instead of math mode and `\frac`?

Comment: Where did you learn this, out of interest?

Comment: I am not familiar with math mode and have used nested tables for equations where necessary before.

Comment: If you're not familiar with TeX's math mode, you really need to make an effort to reverse this alarming state of affairs. Please begin by searching this site for beginners' tools for TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: note it's not just the use of tables that are wrong, `\emph` is not the correct markup, or the correct font, for math italic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong tools for writing math formulas:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
w_{x,y} = tf_{x,y}\log_{10}\biggl(\frac{N}{df_{x}}\biggr)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
w_{x,y} = tf_{x,y}\log_{10}\frac{N}{df_{x}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid those parentheses, like in the second formula.

[image]

Comment: @MrMorgan You should read an introduction to LaTeX, for instance http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  \[ w_{x,y} = \mathit{tf}_{x,y} * \log_{10} \left( \frac{N}{df_x} \right) \]
```

And the answer to the spurious space is: this is the intercolumn space  in a tabular, which can be suppressed with `@{}`

The `\mathit` is to keep the `tf` as a single identifier instead of two.